# Space between string & variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

How can I make this return "Hello yourName" as opposed to "HelloyourName"?

```
    var yourName=(prompt("What's your name?"));
    alert("Hello" + yourName);
```

Comment: `alert("Hello " + yourName);`

Comment: The "yourName" would have spaces too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourName=(prompt("What's your name?"));
alert("Hello " + yourName); // "Hello " with space
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a space character to the string.

This:

```
"Hello" + yourName
```

would resolve to this:

```
HelloJesse
```

whereas this:

```
"Hello " + yourName
   // ^--- added a space
```

would resolve to this:

```
Hello Jesse
```

Comment: Didn't Johnny Mopp in the first comment made provide an effective answer to this?

Comment: Perfect, this answer was succinct and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert("Hello " + yourName.trim());    
alert("Hello" + " " + yourName.trim());
```

I don't see why you cannot add a space between. `yourName.trim()` is to make sure you won't introduce unexpected spaces by `yourname`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a space in between the variables, like so:

```js
var fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
```